# What's going on in this piece of Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me what the following Javascript is doing in terms of the constructors and how it is using / calling the function defined in the variable a?

```
<script>
a = 'alert("Hi");'
{}["apple"]["constructor"]["constructor"](a)();
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is same as `Object.apple.constructor.constructor(a)();`.

Comment: `{}["apple"]["constructor"]["constructor"]` return Function function which can be used the same as eval.

Comment: @Jai it's not the same because `{}` in this case is not an object but empty block. If it was object it will throw exception `Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`

Comment: @Hacketo not String but Array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first `{}` is just a bait, it's interpreted as an empty block and ignored. So we have

```
["apple"]["constructor"]["constructor"](a)()
```

which is

```
[].constructor.constructor(a)()
```

which is

```
Array.constructor(a)()
```

which is

```
Function(a)()
```

which is

```
(function() { alert('Hi') })()
```

`constructor`s are resolved via prototypes, here's the structure:

[image]

Comment: although I am confused how it went from `Array.constructor(a)()` to `Function(a)()`

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: I hope the pic clarifies that

Comment: @georg the pic definitely helps, but I still don't really get it. Would you happen to have a link to somewhere where this is explained in a bit more detail? If not, no worries. I could find myself, but not 100% sure what I would be looking for

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: these things are described in the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), but it's not particularly readable.

Comment: @georg : Why do we want to `alert("Hi")` like this? Is this the way of dynamically invoking functions?

Comment: @ManojAnavatti: there's no practical sense, it's just a funny js  puzzle.

Comment: Also, not to forget `";"` after `a = 'alert("Hi");';` - at the end of statement if we don't have `{}` after first line.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald out of curiosity, did you have to manually generate this graph, or is there a program that does this for you?

Comment: @DavidL I didnt make the graph, this is the great work of georg... I will be staying tuned as I want to know aswell